# i cant pass the value from table to textbox through dlookup vba ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I dont know why I can't pass the value of `AccountType` (from `TblAccount`) to `Me.txtWAccounType` (textbox from `WithdrawView`).

Pleaes help me, here's my code

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[AccountId]", "TblAccount", "AccountId = '" & txtWAccountId & "'")) Then
 MsgBox "Account Number Doesn't Exist"

 Else
 Me.txtWAccounType.Value = DLookup("[AccountType]", "TblAccount", "AccountId = ' " & Forms![WithdrawView]![txtWAccountId] & "' ")
 MsgBox "Account Number Do Exist"

 End If
```

my goal is to retrieve that `AfterUpdate` of `AccountId. messagebox`, but an "Account Number Does Exist" pops up so it means there is a value, but why doesn't it appear in  `Me.txtWAccounType`?

Comment: Is Me.txtWAccounType binded with some field?,  Debug.print( DLookup("[AccountType]", "TblAccount", "AccountId = ' " & Forms![WithdrawView]![txtWAccountId] & "' ") )  print any value?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because there is no record that matches the criteria.. As you know there is a difference between '123' and ' 123' i.e. there is a 'space' character before the number based on your code.. Just replace the DLookUp as Follows..

```
DLookup("[AccountType]", "TblAccount", "AccountId = '" & Forms![WithdrawView]![txtWAccountId] & "'")
```